# Does magic subschool matter for the Spell Specialization feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats

The [Spell Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-specialization/) feat says:

> Select one spell of a school for which you have taken the Spell Focus
>   feat. Treat your caster level as being two higher for all
>   level-variable effects of the spell.
>
> Every time you gain an even level in the spellcasting class you chose
>   your spell from, you can choose a new spell to replace the spell
>   selected with this feat, and that spell becomes your specialized
>   spell.

Does the feat only matter for the school or does the subschool matter as well?

Example:
I have Spell Focus Evocation. If I use Spell Specialization on Magic Missile, school Evocation [force], can I switch it to Fireball, school Evocation [fire]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Only a spell's school matters to Spell Specialization

The feat [Spell Specialization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spell-specialization/) says, in part, "Select one spell of a school for which you have taken the Spell Focus feat." The feat just doesn't care at all about a spell's subschool or its descriptors. A caster that possesses Spell Focus (evocation) can pick for the feat Spell Specialization the spell *magic missile* as easily as the spell *fireball*… or the spell [*wall of force*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-force/) or even the spell [*contingency*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency/).

By the way, the school of [evocation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Evocation) doesn't have subschools like, for instance, the school of [illusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Illusion) has the subschools figment, glamer, and others. When a spell has a term in parentheses after the spell's school, that's a spell's subschool. When a spell has a term in brackets after the spell's school, that's a spell's [descriptor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Descriptor-). For example, the spell [*magic missile*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-missile/) is in the school of evocation and possesses the descriptor force, the spell [*fireball*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball/) is in the school evocation and possesses the descriptor fire, and the spell [charm person](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/charm-person/) is in the enchantment school, the charm subschool, and possesses the descriptor mind-affecting. This may all seem very pedantic—and, to a degree, it is—, but the game cares about these distinctions, like in the description of the feat Spell Specialization.

Answer (score 1):

The text of the feat only mentions the complete school, so as long as it's in the same school it means subschool shouldn't matter.